# How can i place the drop zones in inclined boxes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable, droppable

I have to drag the rows of a table into the inclined boxes. The problem is that the drop zone is not on the inclined box. How to bring the drop zone on each inclined boxes properly?

Code snippet is as below:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#dragTbl tr').draggable({
    cursor:"move", 
    zIndex: 100,
    cursorAt: {top:20, left:38, bottom:15 },
    iframeFix: true,
    helper: function( event ) { 
      return $( "<div class='drag-item'>"+ $(this).attr('id') +"</div>" );
    },
    start: function() {
    },
    drag: function() {   
    },
    stop: function(){
    }                               
  }); 

  $('.dropCol').droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function( event, ui ){
      var ids = ui.draggable.attr('id');                           
      var avail = $(this).find('.tx').text().length == 0 ? true : false;
      if(avail){
        $(this).find('.tx').text(ids);
        $(this).find('.tx').prev().val(ids);
        $('#'+ids).draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
      }else{
        return;
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.dropCol{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f2f3f3;
  //transform: rotate(20deg);
  float:left;
}

#dropTbl{
  width:100%;
}

.drag-item{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #675C5C;
  color:white;
  padding:10px; // 7px;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius:20px;
}

.tx{
  //margin-left:-98px;
  margin-top: 135px;
}

.eleDiv{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 17px;
  //margin-left:-72px;
}

.rht-mrgn{
  margin-right:45px;        
}        
.lft-mrgn{
  margin-left:45px;        
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
                <!-- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX FOR INCLINED TYPE BOXES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -->
                
  <div>
    <center>
      <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="count"/>
      <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <div id="dropTbl">                                            
              <apex:repeat value="{!lftmodList}" var="mod">
                <div id="{!count}" class="dropCol {!IF(count = lftmodList.size ,'rht-mrgn','')}" style="height:270px;transform: rotate(20deg);">
                  <apex:inputHidden value="{!mod.lbl}"/>
                  <p class="tx"></p> 
                </div>
                <apex:variable value="{!count+1}" var="count"/>
              </apex:repeat>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid #000;min-width:65px;transform: rotate(0deg);">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="5" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <div id="dropTbl">
              <apex:repeat value="{!rhtmodList}" var="mod">
                <div id="{!count}" class="dropCol {!IF(count = lftmodList.size+1 ,'lft-mrgn','')}" style="height:270px;transform: rotate(-20deg);">
                  <apex:inputHidden value="{!mod.lbl}"/>
                  <p class="tx"></p> 
                </div>
                <apex:variable value="{!count+1}" var="count"/>
              </apex:repeat>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="12" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <div style="width:100%;float: left;">
              <div class="eleDiv">
                <span><b>Element Posiotion</b></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>                                  
        </tr>                        
      </table>
    </center>
  </div>
  </apex:outputPanel> 

<!-- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx FOR FLAT TYPE BOXES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -->
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(type == 'Flat',true,false)}">  
  <table id="dropTbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:55%;">
    <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="count"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!modList}" var="mod">
      <tr>
        <td id="{!count}" class="dropCol" style="height:32px;">
          <apex:inputHidden value="{!mod.lbl}"/>
          <p class="tx" style="transform: rotate(-21deg);"></p> 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <apex:variable value="{!count+1}" var="count"/>
    </apex:repeat>
  </table>

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" style="width: 55%;margin-top:5px;text-align: center;">
    <td colspan="{!modList.size+2}" style="vertical-align:middle;height:50px;"><b>Element Posiotion</b></td>
  </table>
</apex:outputPanel>
</div>
```